# Pandas dataframe diff between rows with column offset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with the following structure

| time_start | time_end | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| time | time + 1 | action |
| time + 1 | time + 2 | some_other_action |

I would like to take see the diff of `time_start` and previous row `time_end`. in this case `(time + 1) - (time + 1) = 0`
I have tried `df.diff`, but that only yields the diff within either columns or rows.

Any ideas of how I can perform this "jagged diff"?

Comment: `df['time_start'] - df['time_end'].shift()`.

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang , it worked like a charm. I'm posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was what @Quang Hoang mentioned in a comment.

`df['time_start'] - df['time_end'].shift(periods=1)`

Note that periods can be negative to shift in the other direction.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html